# PHPMYADMIN LAST_INSERT_ID returns 0

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, lastinsertid, last-insert-id

I have problem with `LAST_INSERT_ID`.

```
CREATE TABLE for_test(
id_test INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
test_name VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO for_test (test_name) VALUES ('test1');
INSERT INTO for_test (test_name) VALUES ('test2');
```

I added successfully two records - yet `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` still returns 0. (I use InnoDB if that even matters)

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried using `mysql_insert_id()`

Comment: @atoms: mysql_insert_id is PHP function. 
on phpmyadmin it will return 0 always. Use it on procedure/function and you will get the result.

Comment: just a side note: the last_insert_id could also be the last inserted id from someone else from some other table. **unless* you use transactions!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No other query after insert and they both should execute together. Be careful that. Also if you can not handle it you can use

```
SELECT id FROM for_test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

and you can read this manual

[How to use LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped a lot :)

Comment: I am glad that it. So I hope you will click "This answer is useful button". Have a nice developments :)

Answer (score 0):

you should try mysqli example

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: As Riad said - mysqli it's PHP function and I'm using PHPMyAdmin console

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE for_test(
id_test INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
test_name VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO for_test (test_name) VALUES ('test1');
INSERT INTO for_test (test_name) VALUES ('test2');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Note: it's working with Engine - InnoDB in phpMyAdmin.
if you still have same problem, will you please send error snapshot, so that we can track exact issue.

Hope this will help you!!